# Animated Text SVG insert not according to what I typed

Tags: html, svg

[MY JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/roioffeo/z496kant/)

```
<div id="main-canvas-container" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"> 
   THIS IS WHERE I PLACE THE SVG'S
</div>
```

On my jsfiddle it shows a div container with a lot of svg's inserted. By default I inserted it as A,B,C,D,E,F,F

but what appears in there is A,F,G,B,C,E

I check if it has something to do with the size of the JSON file but it isn't.

Any Idea what's causing it?

If I type in to insert ABCD then it is correct but when it comes to E, it will be inserted between C and D resulting to ABCED.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: presumably the extra letters are falling off the end of the canvas

Comment: It's not the extra letters. My point is If I insert ABCDE it will be inserted as ABCED

Comment: All thats in the fiddle is the resulting HTML, we would need to be able to see that code that generated the HTML to diagnose whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is correct. The SVGs are displaying in the order they appear in the HTML.  The first one is "A". The second one is "F" etc.  You can confirm this yourself by removing them one-by-one from the fiddle.

Either you have the SVG files mislabelled when you insert them.  Or if you are inserting them with code, then there must be an issue with that code.